# How can I have two phones connected to my Pi4?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I need to have two phones connected to my Pi4 through USB so I can run different tasks on them automatically using appium.

If I just connect one phone, everything is ok. But if I connect the second one, the port goes crazy. Like the first one will stop being connected (and charging) for 1 second while the is charging, then 1 second later the charging switches back to the first one and soo on in an infinite loop.

I thought this is a power problem, so I disabled fast charging on both phones. Also, I tried setting " max_usb_current = 1 " in config. Nothing worked. What other options do I have?

Comment: How much power / current does your power supply have?

Comment: Maybe try a powered USB hub and see if that addresses the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to buy a powered USB hub. It works perfectly with up to 6 phones now, and the PI doesn't get hot at all. Great stuff.